# Can't connect an already booted device to adb

Tags: usb, adb, connection-issues

Every time I want to connect my phone to `adb` via USB I need to turn it off, plug the cable and turn it back on.

Is this the right way to go or am I missing something?

[Documen](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html)[tation](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) doesn't seem to explicitly state that.

Some details:

- Samsung GT-B5510 Galaxy Y Pro (Android 2.3.6)
- Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.29
- Debian GNU/Linux 7.0 (wheezy)

Comment: Hi cYrus, some more info on make/model and Android version would be helpful. You're right, your phone's behaviour is not standard.

Comment: Is USB debugging enabled?

Comment: @ce4: Added some more infos.

Comment: @LiamW: Sure, as I said, I manage to get it working if I turn on the device with the USB cable plugged.

Comment: Ok, as a start you could see if adb is running from within Android. Install [terminal emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm) and run `ps | grep adb` (you should see somthing like: *shell     2818  1     4496   200   ffffffff 00000000 S /sbin/adbd* if it runs). If it does only run after you booted it with usb plugged in, it's a problem with your device. It's probably fixable, but that requires root. Ping me in the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25/android) it's probably faster to discuss there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the real issue cYrus had (we tracked it down via interactive chat):

The phone has obviously some race condition between **plugging USB in** and **USB ready**. Plugging in basically gives 2 events:

- Power connected event (start charging battery)
- USB connected event (enumerate devices etc.)

If the Host system asks for USB enumeration too quickly (before the power-connected event has settled probably), then that operation fails and the device stays invisible.

The workaround is to slowly insert the USB cable.

Reason: USB has 4 pins, the 2 outer ones are +/- and protrude longer than the inner 2 data pins. If inserted slowly, there's a time gap between the power-connected event and the data-connected event

Comment: You need to be nice to your phone, hehe. Open a can of jokes now... :-)

Answer (score 1):

I have had similar trouble with a different device.  After you plug you device in try:

```
adb devices
```

If your phone is not listed, try restarting ADB:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

Lastly, check if there are any driver updates for your phone.  A good place to start looking for drivers is [Google's OEM page](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html) and [Samsung's support page](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/downloads).  Additional tips might be found on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256884/android-device-chooser-device-not-showing-up/11456687#11456687).

Comment: Restarting `adb` makes no difference, I'll check for driver updates, stay tuned...

Comment: Forgot to mention: I'm using Linux.